# Wordpress "Categories to tags converter" not working. Pointing to import.php instead

Tags: wordpress, tags, converters, categories, blogger

I just imported my posts from blogger into wordpress. In doing this, the tags were converted to categories for some strange reason.

I am now trying to convert them back into tag using wordpress' built in converter. However, whenever I click on the "Category to tag converter" link, it directs me to the import page "/import.php". Is there anything i can do to rectify this.

Alternatively, could someone please copy the end of the URL for the converter tool's page, and paste it here so i can append it to my blog URL. Im guessing that could work meanwhile.

Cheers in advance..

Comment: Not a programming question, try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com or the WP forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /importer.php document is pointing you to the right place. If you look at that page again, you can see at the bottom there is this line:

- Categories and Tags Converter - Install the category/tag converter to convert existing categories to tags or tags to categories, selectively.

It's a plugin you can install. Once you've done that, you can do all kinds of modifications to your tags/categories.

The link to the plugin once installed is:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wpcat2tag
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen the importer plugin. However, i have already imported my posts from Blogger and it is already in my wordpress database. However, the issue is that for some reason the **tags** which were given to my posts in Blogger have been converted to **categories** in wordpress. So right now i have about a thousand categories. I am trying to convert all these categories into tags

Comment: Wait a minute.. there's a plugin listed there as well called "categories and tags converter" :)